# Change button size bootstrap 4 (Django)

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I'm working with Django and I'm trying to line up a Bootstrap button with a select field. I've got the form inline where I'd like it to be, but I can't seem to make the button smaller to make it align properly. I'm sure there is a simple solution but I've been struggling with this for hours and can't seem to find anything that works for me. Here is a picture as it is currently to give you a better idea of the problem: [button not aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRzWI.png)

And here is my current code in my template:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="{% url 'displayStats:proindvleaders'%}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
</div>
```

I've tried just setting height on the button ID with css but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default bootstrap btn class has padding. Inspect the code in a browser and remove that padding, either by adding a new padding class, or use custom styling class and remove btn, btn-primary etc, but all the same, its better to edit the form, rather than button. Bootstrap default buttons are perfect for most scenario, and most probably you need form styling. I suggest form styling. Below is an example from code.
Ps: i'm replying from phone, code may not be formatted

`{% for field in form %}

     <div class="fieldWrapper">{{ field.errors }}
     <input  type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}"  name="{{ field.html_name }}"  id="{{field.id_for_label}}"   class="col-12 input-login" placeholder="{{field.label}}"  >
     {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
     {% endif %}
     </div>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: Thanks my friend, it seems simpler to style the form as you have suggested - especially in my case as the 'form' is actually just a single Choice Field.

Comment: Thankyou, sometimes the solution to problems are simpler alternative, although i do recommend creating a few custom templates for forms. If there are a lot of form fields, it is more efficient. Please refer simpleisbetterthancomplex.com, vitor has explained it as simple as possible

Comment: That site looks like a great resource, I have saved it for future reference! Here is my perfectly lined up field: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/38be198cf14b73aaf28e6d92199b1064.png)
Happy holidays and thanks again!